# Laravel dusk maintain browser sessions other than user model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I am a totally Laravel Dusk noob, started using it recently. Here is my dusk test method -

```
public function test_show_new_customer(): void
{
    $this->login()->use_application(6);

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
        $browser->loginAs($this->user)
            ->visit(new NewCustomerPage())
            ->assertTitle('New Customer');
    });
}
```

But, while executing this test I am getting a 401 error.

Here is my middleware where it throws an error -

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $has_app_access = User::hasAppAccess(session('business.id'));
    
    if (!$has_app_access) {
        abort(401);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Error is given due to there being no session found for business id, hence it validates that there is no application access for the logged-in user. When I dump `dd(session('business.id'))` gives me a `null`.

I want to set a browser session before visiting a page. Is this possible in Laravel Dusk?

Comment: is this still an active issue that you need help with?

Comment: yes, it is still an active issue and I am looking for a solution. It would be appreciated if you can help me with it @oelimoe

Comment: there is an likelyhood that the login function doesnt work correctly and the login was false that would explain why the user doesnt get the access

Comment: i always like to check where it goes wrong visualy so i use the laravel dusk function "->screenshot("name")"